# center flash element based on the elements actual size 2

Tags: css, apache-flex, dynamic

I everybody,

I have qustioned this question already in that post:

[center flash element based on the elements actual size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355481/center-flash-element-based-on-the-elements-actual-size)

but I didn't find any usable solution. I guess its quite tricky so I re ask the question here:

how can I place a swf file in my webpage when the width of the file changes according to the user input. What I need is a sort of a dynamic css...

any idea?

Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I'm reading you're confused. A flash object does not change sizes once it is loaded. If you loaded it at 100% width, it's filling 100% of the page width-wise. Whether or not the content *inside* the flash object fills that entire object is another question. If use input is 'changing' the size of the object, it's only changing the size of the objects inside of flash and not the object which is loaded in the page itself, the width of the flash object is always remaining the same. You should be looking into how to center your content inside flash based on the width of your object, which I'm pretty sure is possible using something like `_root._width` or something, but I haven't used ActionScript in ages.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is, that there is no way to do what I need to! At least I now it know! then I need to rethink my app! Thanks for your quick response, Markus